# IIS multiple HTTPS web sites with different host headers

Tags: iis-7.5, windows-server-2008

I've got so far with this and hit a brick wall. I have set up **4 web sites on one server** in IIS:

1. **Default Web Site** (myserver.mydomain.com)
   D:\websites\default\
2. **Apple** (apple.mydomain.com)
   D:\websites\apple\
3. **Orange** (orange.mydomain.com)
   D:\websites\orange\
4. **Pear** (orange.mydomain.com)
   D:\websites\pear\

I have configured the site bindings using the command line as per [this guide](http://www.sslshopper.com/article-ssl-host-headers-in-iis-7.html) and it now looks like I want it to. When I do **appcmd list sites** it returns the following:

```
SITE "Default Web Site" (id:1,bindings:net.tcp/808:*,net.pipe/*,net.msmq/localhost,msmq.formatname/localhost,https/*:443:,state:Started)
SITE "apple" (id:2,bindings:https/*:443:apple.syfire.gov.uk,state:Started)
SITE "orange" (id:3,bindings:https/*:443:orange.syfire.gov.uk,state:Started)
SITE "pear" (id:4,bindings:https/*:443:pear.syfire.gov.uk,state:Started)
```

Results:

- "myserver.mydomain.com" returns the error `Server Error in Application "DEFAULT WEB SITE"
  HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
  The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.` despite there being a Default Document configured (index.html). **EDIT**: If I switch Directory Browsing **on** it shows the contents of D:\websites\default\ (as it should) and I can navigate to *index.html*, but when it's off it can't seem to find the file itself.
- "apple.mydomain.com" works fine and shows the default page stored in `D:\websites\apple\`.
- "orange.mydomain.com" and "pear.mydomain.com" return error `Server not found` (Firefox), `Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage` (IE).

I'm sure I've missed something critical to this operation! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing * with the ip address that you are listening on.  This is what I used to get something similar to work in IIS 6 on Windows 2003.